# How to download multiple images from Server using URL in Client Side

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am using this tutorial:
http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery-swipe-gallery/

here he has used drawable images, but now i want to use Server Images

**ImageAdapter.java:**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
R.drawable.one,
R.drawable.two,
R.drawable.three
};
ImageAdapter(Context context){
this.context=context;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
return GalImages.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}
}
```

Still i am using Images path like this:

```
R.drawable.one,
R.drawable.two,
R.drawable.three
```

But now i want to use Images path like below:

```
http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/bloglogo1.png,
http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/bloglogo2.png,
http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/bloglogo3.png
```

Comment: convert your image url to bitmap and after that set that bitmap to imageview

Comment: @ShaniGoriwal hi dude can you show me the code?

Comment: yes you can post here

Comment: @ShaniGoriwal i am using this tutorial: http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery-swipe-gallery/

Comment: but it is for static images and also for int array.

Comment: @ShaniGoriwal yes bro i just need to download 10 limited images from url everytime

Comment: Ok..first after retrieving images url from server are you add it in arraylist..isn't it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35142/discussion-between-abrahim-neil-and-shani-goriwal)

Comment: @AbrahimNeil Are your total number of urls fixed ? Or you are not sure howmuch urls will be there .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to do anything using the reference http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/ .

Just create the Array of string which contains the urls as

```
    String[] imagUrl={
            http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/bloglogo1.png,
            http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/bloglogo2.png,
           http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/bloglogo3.png };
```

After creating array just copy the files `ImageLoader.java`,`FileCache.java`,`MemoryCache.java` and `Utils.java` in your application.

And after that in your adapter class do as following.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // Imageview to show
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    // ImageLoader class instance
    ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
     // Loader image - will be shown before loading image
    int loader = R.drawable.loader;
    // whenever you want to load an image from url
    // call DisplayImage function
    // url - image url to load
    // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
    // image - ImageView 
    imgLoader.DisplayImage(imagUrl[position], loader, imageView );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use image loader

for reference

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/